# How to resize inline buttons in a Telegram bot?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram-api

Tell me pls, how to resize inline (not reply) buttons in a Telegram bot? The docs does not say anything at all about the resize of inline buttons.

Code:

```
foreach ($sections as $section) {
  $arrKeyboard[] = [
    'text' => $section->getTitle(),
    'callback_data' => '....'
  ];
}

$keyboard = new \TelegramBot\Api\Types\Inline\InlineKeyboardMarkup([$arrKeyboard]);
$telegramBot->sendMessage($message->getChat()->getId(), $answer, 'markdown', false, null, $keyboard);
```

[image: How it looks]

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($sections as $section) {
  $arrKeyboard[] = [
    [
        'text' => $section->getTitle(),
        'callback_data' => '....'
    ]
  ];
}

$keyboard = new \TelegramBot\Api\Types\Inline\InlineKeyboardMarkup($arrKeyboard);
$telegramBot->sendMessage($message->getChat()->getId(), $answer, 'markdown', false, null, $keyboard);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_chunk` function to set how many items should be displayed in each row.

```
foreach ($sections as $section) {
  $arrKeyboard[] = [
    [
        'text' => $section->getTitle(),
        'callback_data' => '....'
    ]
  ];
}
array_chunk($arrKeyboard,2); // this will show 2 items in each row of inline keyboard.
```